# Kronecker product calculation in multiplying two matrix

Tags: matrices, kronecker-product

$$
    \mathbf \Phi =\begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf p_1^T \mathbf \otimes Q^*   \\
    \mathbf p_2^T \mathbf \otimes Q^*\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
    \mathbf p_{Mt}^T \mathbf \otimes Q^*  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

and $\mathbf Q=[\mathbf q_1   \mathbf q_2 ...\mathbf q_{Mr}],\mathbf P=[\mathbf p_1  \mathbf p_2 ...\mathbf p_{Mt}],\mathbf q_i^* \mathbf q_i=||\mathbf q_i||^2_2=\gamma,||\mathbf P||^2_F= P,\mathbf q_i$ is a $N_r \times 1$ matrix  ,and $\mathbf p_i$ is a $N_t \times 1$ matrix

And  the paper said  $\mathbf \Phi \mathbf \Phi ^* =\frac{\gamma P}{N_t N_r} \mathbf I$,and i think it just

$$
    \mathbf \Phi  \mathbf \Phi^*=\begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf p_1^T \mathbf \otimes Q^*   \\
    \mathbf p_2^T \mathbf \otimes Q^*\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
    \mathbf p_{Mt}^T \mathbf \otimes Q^*  \\
    \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf p_1^T \mathbf \otimes Q^*   \\
    \mathbf p_2^T \mathbf \otimes Q^*\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
    \mathbf p_{Mt}^T \mathbf \otimes Q^*  \\
    \end{bmatrix}^*
$$
and may be some reason to let the formula become  $\mathbf q_i ^* \mathbf q_i=\gamma$ ,and $\mathbf p_i ^* \mathbf p_i=P$,but i don't know how do thy really calculate it,so i want to ask,does anyone know about that?

And why should $\gamma P \mathbf I $ divided by $N_t N_r$,that is ,divided by the dimension of $\mathbf p_i$ and $\mathbf q_i$

By the way,i think "*" means transpose conjugate,$||\mathbf P||_F=\sqrt{trace(\mathbf P^* \mathbf P)}$

Comment: It looks like we have $\Phi = P^T \otimes Q^*$

Comment: indeed it is ,but $\Phi$ is also a matrix too

Comment: @Omnomnomnom So do you know how to calculate  $\Phi \times \Phi $ to $\frac{\gamma P \mathbf I}{N_t N_r}$,and why should  $\gamma P \mathbf I $ be divided by $N_t N_r$?

Comment: If $\mathbf \Phi = \mathbf P^T \otimes \mathbf Q^*$ then $\mathbf \Phi \mathbf \Phi^* = (\mathbf P^* \cdot \mathbf P)^T \otimes (\mathbf Q^* \mathbf Q)$ which is only equal to an identity matrix if both $\mathbf P$ and $\mathbf Q$ are left-unitary so that $\mathbf P^* \cdot \mathbf P = \mathbf I$ and $\mathbf Q^* \cdot \mathbf Q = \mathbf I$. Are they?